# Distribution of error values in linear regression vs logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, logistic-regression, distribution

Why do error values in linear regression have to be normally distributed and why not in logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

Lets clarify with a simpler question

> Why points on a circle must be equally distanced from center, but
>   not points on a square?

Because of how circle and square are "defined". The same goes for linear and logistic regression, we cannot pose a "why?" question when errors are "defined" in a certain way (or a better word here "assumed"). We may design a new version of linear regression by replacing Normal distribution with some other distribution, and then proceed to derive a formula or algorithm for estimating the parameters. Then use it in a real-world scenario to see how it works, and so on.

Also here is a list of good posts on stats.stackexchange.com related to characteristics of those errors:

1. [Error distribution for linear and logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37776/error-distribution-for-linear-and-logistic-regression),
2. [Logistic Regression - Error Term and its Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124818/logistic-regression-error-term-and-its-distribution).